# How to unit test webrtc app?

Tags: unit-testing, webrtc

How do you check your connection script works ?

How do you test you got a media stream ?

That you received data from the stream ?

How do you mock that up ?

How do you do without an internet connection and one computer ?

Comment: Have you got the answer of this question?

Comment: A few links : http://blog.andyet.com/2014/09/29/testing-webrtc-applications and http://googletesting.blogspot.se/2014/08/chrome-firefox-webrtc-interop-test-pt-1.html

Answer (score 0):

i was just about to tell you that it's impossible but then I realized nothing is impossible...

https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/

download mongoose web server. serve up your pages locally.
use  chrome and firefox.. start communication and have fun..

requires one computer, no internet=)

Comment: This is not unit testing, this is end to end testing. Plus to automate this, you'll need more than mongoose, you'll need something like selenium.